# How to stop my RecyclerView reuse the view

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-recyclerview

My question is: when I scroll my page , some views will appear in a new place , not all my content from the adapter will be display but only some sort of them .
below is my adapter class:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<BabyFigure> rinfoList ;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView id,date,time,type,quantity,demo;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_id);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_date);
        time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_time);
        type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_type);
        quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_quantity);
        demo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_demo);
    }
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<BabyFigure> infoList) {
    this.rinfoList = infoList;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_content,
            parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),String.valueOf(rinfoList.size()));
    return rinfoList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder,int position) {
    BabyFigure babyFigure = rinfoList.get(position);
    holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(babyFigure.getQuantity()));
    holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(babyFigure.getId()));
    holder.demo.setText(babyFigure.getDemo());
    holder.date.setText(babyFigure.getDate());
    holder.time.setText(babyFigure.getTime());
    holder.type.setText(babyFigure.getType());
}
```

}

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you didn't implement `getItemId()`. You are calling the superclass implementation, which simply returns the same value for all positions.

At the very least, you can do this:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

But if your data items actually have meaningful IDs, you should return the ID of the item instead.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rinfoList.get(position).getId();
}
```

Comment: Indeed , I overrode the getItemId method , but I use "return super.getItemID(position)" instead . Anyway , I follow your advice , and it works , thank you so much

Comment: It is not working for me... can you please help me set getItem id? I am using ArrayList<Object>, beacuse of that i am not able to get id

Comment: @JadavLalit Ideally you should be using something more meaningful and specific than `Object` to represent your items. The ID is some logical value that uniquely identifies a particular item. What that means for your specific use case is for you to determine and implement.

Comment: getItemId is not getting called in Recyclerview Adapter